# Convert a string into an integer of its ascii values

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, join, ascii

I am trying to write a function that takes a string `txt` and returns an int of that string's character's ascii numbers. It also takes a second argument, `n`, that is an int that specified the number of digits that each character should translate to. The default value of n is 3. n is always > 3 and the string input is always non-empty.

Example outputs:

```
string_to_number('fff')
102102102

string_to_number('ABBA', n = 4)
65006600660065
```

My current strategy is to split `txt` into its characters by converting it into a list. Then, I convert the characters into their `ord` values and append this to a new list. I then try to combine the elements in this new list into a number (e.g. I would go from `['102', '102', '102']` to `['102102102']`. Then I try to convert the first element of this list (aka the only element), into an integer. My current code looks like this:

```
def string_to_number(txt, n=3):
    characters = list(txt)
    ord_values = []


for character in characters:
    ord_values.append(ord(character))

    joined_ord_values = ''.join(ord_values)
    final_number = int(joined_ord_values[0])

    return final_number
```

The issue is that I get a `Type Error`. I can write code that successfully returns the integer of a single-character string, however when it comes to ones that contain more than one character, I can't because of this type error. Is there any way of fixing this. Thank you, and apologies if this is quite long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def string_to_number(text, n=3):
    return int(''.join('{:0>{}}'.format(ord(c), n) for c in text))

print(string_to_number('fff'))
print(string_to_number('ABBA', n=4))
```

Output:

```
102102102
65006600660065
```

---

**Edit:** without list comprehension, as OP asked in the comment

```
def string_to_number(text, n=3):
    l = []
    for c in text:
        l.append('{:0>{}}'.format(ord(c), n))
    return int(''.join(l))
```

---

Useful link(s):

- [string formatting in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html): contains pretty much everything you need to know about string formatting in python

Comment: That certainly worked, thank you! Is there a way of writing that not in list comprehension? Just for my own comprehension...I'd like to be able to point out which part of the code does what.

Comment: @IndifferentPotato Take a look at the edit. And if it helped you, upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer. :)

Comment: @IndifferentPotato You are welcome. I could also use an upvote ;-)

Comment: I have one last question, how would I reverse this code to get it to do the opposite. That is, take a num and convert it into its corresponding string?

Comment: @IndifferentPotato that's a separate question don't you think? Still, I will help. In that case you need the value of `n` used for that particular string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552973/convert-an-integer-into-a-string-of-its-ascii-values, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` method expects an array of strings, so you'll need to convert your ASCII codes into strings.  This almost gets it done:

```
ord_values.append(str(ord(character)))
```

except that it doesn't respect your number-of-digits requirement.