# Convert an integer into a string of its ascii values

Tags: python, string, list, int, ascii

Given a number `number` such that its digits are grouped into parts of length `n` (default value of `n` is 3) where each group represents some ascii value, I want to convert `number` into a string of those ascii characters. For example:

```
n                number     Output
==================================
3                    70          F
3           65066066065       ABBA
4        65006600660065       ABBA
```

Note that there is no leading `0` in number, so the first ascii value will not necessarily be represented with `n` digits.

My current code looks like this:

```
def number_to_string(number, n=3):
    number = str(number)
    segment = []

    while number:
        segment.append(number[:n])
        number = number[n:]

    return str(''.join('{:0>{}}'.format(chr(segment), n) for segment in number))
```

Expected outputs:

```
number_to_string(70)
'F'

number_to_string(65066066065)
'ABBA'

number_to_string(65006600660065, n=4)
'ABBA'
```

My current code however returns an empty string. For example, instead of 'F' it returns `' '`. Any reason why this is? Thank you!

---

P.S.:
I'm wanting to reverse the process of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550447/convert-a-string-into-an-integer-of-its-ascii-values), i.e. turn an integer into a string based on the ascii values of each character (number) in the string. But reading that question is not a requirement to answer this one.

Comment: It's easier for the rest of us if you ask a self-contained question.  We shouldn't need to read through another question/answer/comment set to understand this one.

Comment: Your loop condition is `while number:`.  This means that the loop will keep running while `number` has something left in it, and will stop when `number` is empty.  Therefore, when you get to the `return` statement, `number` is empty, leaving nothing for the `format` call to operate on, thus an empty string is returned.  (I'm assuming that `for segment in num` is a typo and should actually be `for segment in number`.)

Comment: Okay that makes some sense, thank you. How would I fix this? And yes it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

def number_to_string(num, n=3):
    num_str = str(num)
    if len(num_str) < n:
        num_str = '0' * (n-len(num_str)) + num_str
    elif len(num_str) % n != 0:
        num_str = '0'*(n-len(num_str)%n) + num_str
    print(num_str)

    chars = re.findall('.'*n, num_str)
    l = [chr(int(i)) for i in chars]
    return ''.join(l)
```

First pad the given number (converted into string) with required number of zeros, so that it can be evenly split into equal number of characters each. Then using `re` split the string into segments of size `n`. Finally convert each chunk into character using `chr`, and then join them using `join`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; OP wanted to know why his existing code didn't work.

Comment: This works for the input of 70, however for the other inputs it returns a weird combination. For example, for '65066066065' it returns ' '\x06Ǻɞɞ' '.

Comment: @IndifferentPotato Try the edited code. I did a small mistake.

Comment: You are a legend, thank you! It's always great to see alternate ways of solving problems.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to have helped ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
def numToStr(inp):
"""Take a number and make a sequence of bytes in a string"""
out=""
while inp!=0:
    out=chr(inp & 255)+out
    inp=inp>>8
print "num2string:", out 
return out
```

does this help?

Comment: This works for the first example input, however for the other it returns a funny output. Eg for 65066066065 it returns '\x91'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def num_to_string(num, leng):
    string = ""
    for i in range(0,len(str(num)),leng):
        n = str(num)[i:i+2]
        string += chr(int(n))
    print string
```

Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> num_to_string(650065006600,4)
AAB
>>> num_to_string(650650660,3)
AAB
>>> num_to_string(656566,2)
AAB
>>>
```

Comment: For this input 6600660123, your code fails. To be specific, it will fail for ascii codes with 3 digits.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Are the digits for ascii codes fixed for letters in one string?

Answer (score -1):

You can just append \x to number as this prints 'p':

```
print '\x70'
```